# ¿Qué hace "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main"?

Tags: java, ubuntu, debian

Cuando pusé en la terminal como `root` el comando `apt-get update` me apareció en una línea del output esto:

`Des:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease [15,4 kB]`

Buscando con mi ignorancia un poco encontré esta [página en inglés](https://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-debian/) donde al parecer (con lo poco que entiendo) me informa que cuando alguien instaló java en mi computador pusieron este comando:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main`

Mi pregunta es ¿Qué hace este comando?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es una pregunta de programación.

Comment: Y si pregunto que hace `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main` ?

Comment: ese mensaje indica que apt solicitó los updates del repositorio indicado para la versión trusty de ubuntu (v 14 LTS)

Comment: btw `disco InRelease` es la versión 19 de ubuntu https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/disco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como podrás ver en [esta respuesta de askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233064/why-am-i-getting-command-deb-not-found/233069) **`deb` NO es un comando**, sino que es la forma en que en el archivo se indica **un repositorio de Debian**, es decir de paquetes de debian.

Como ubuntu usa por defecto paquetes debian en vez de otro tipo de paquetes tal vez por ello te cause confusión.

Comment: Pero `deb` no descarga `http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main` entonces?

Comment: no, deb no es un comando